# Syntax/indentation problems with Vue mode in Emacs 27 nightly

Tags: indentation, syntax-table, emacs27

I'm using `vue-mode`, based on `mmm-mode` with Emacs 27 nightly from 10/10/2019. Since that Emacs update, I don't get any indentation support in the script section of a Vue file.
Try this file with `emacs -q` after `(use-package vue)`:

```
<template>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import * as d3 from 'd3'
  function foo() {

  }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Go into function `foo` at the blank line and type TAB. No indent. :-(

And indeed if you eval `(syntax-ppss (point-at-bol))` at that point, it returns `(0 nil 2381 nil nil nil 0 nil nil nil nil)` which means it thinks the indent should be 0, not 2.

Anyone have any idea what changed recently that could cause this?
Or any ideas for how I can debug it?

Comment: Emacs.StackExchange isn't the right place to report bugs in unstable Emacs versions.  Use `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's probably about a transient bug in unstable code.

Comment: Fair enough. Submitted as bug #37751.

Comment: The problem manifests in stable emacs 26.3, too.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been reported as [#99](https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode/issues/99) and already fixed in master of [mmm-mode](https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode), but since there is no new release, you have to install the newest *mmm-mode* manually, or add the missing setting to `mmm-save-local-variables` -- for example with `use-package`:

```lisp
(use-package vue-mode
  :mode "\\.vue$"
  :config
  (add-to-list 'mmm-save-local-variables '(syntax-ppss-table buffer))
  )
```

Comment: See also related bug #100 (https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode/issues/100). Also add this to your .emacs:
`(add-to-list 'mmm-save-local-variables '(c-current-comment-prefix region))`

Answer (score 1):

Update for 2023 - there is a new release so if you do list-packages and install the latest mmm-mode (20230917.28 at the time of writing) and restart emacs it'll just work.